# Close the previous infoWindow with Angular Map @agm

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am asking a question that many people ask, but no one gave a clear answer, almost on AGM (Angular 2 package for Google map)

Here is my code, but my first opened marker does not want to close, and the other markers close half the time

```
clickedMarker(marker: Marker, infoWindow, index: number) {

   if (this.infoWindow && this.infoWindow !== infoWindow) {
      this.infoWindow.close();
    }
    this.infoWindow = infoWindow;
}
```

Can someone help me to fix this close problem, using the close function or the event emitter https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/AgmInfoWindow.html#source

Thanks for your time and help ;)

**EDIT : FOUND THE ANSWER**

I had my `<agm-info-window #infoWindow>` displaying multiple information using `<a *ngIf="myCondition"..>{{address}}</a>` but it looks like it was not rendering the popup when the condition was evaluate to true again.

I replaced it by `<a [class.hidden]="!myCondition">..</a>` and it fixed the multiple display of markers.

Another good practice is to close when there is a click on map, and to close it if opened :

```
clickedMap($event) {
   if (this.infoWindow) {
      this.infoWindow.close();
   }
}
```

It might help in the future... who knows ?

Comment: Are you trying to close the marker's infowindow on click of the marker? It's not that clear what your goal is. Would you be able to create a self-contained working example by building off the [agm demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YX7W20?p=preview)?

Comment: I want to close every infoWindow when a new marker is cliked, here is a working demo (https://westi.co/static/mapv2), just create an adresse with name and categoy and click on the two markers multiple times. The problem is that it does not close the previous window all the time, but half the time :/

Comment: Nice that you solved it! You could insert more sample code to help others out. You'll see the value of a working isolated minimal example (not entire website). As with just the info you provided, it would be hard to come to your solution :)

Comment: The solution is in my EDIT section added recently :)

Comment: Look here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003652/angular-google-map-close-info-window-on-new-marker-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003652/angular-google-map-close-info-window-on-new-marker-click) ;)

Answer (score 13):

After a long research and unclear solutions a finally got a fine solution for clear previous agm-info-window when a new one is opened

This is my component.html:

```
 <agm-map (mapClick)="close_window($event)" [fullscreenControl]='true' [mapTypeControl]='true' [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="13" [scrollwheel]="false">
     <div *ngFor="let data of zonas">
        <agm-marker (markerClick)=select_marker(infoWindow) [latitude]="data.latitud" [longitude]="data.longitud">
           <agm-info-window #infoWindow >            
           </agm-info-window>
         </agm-marker>
      </div>
  </agm-map>
```

And this is my component.ts:

```
constructor(public apiService: ApiService) {}
infoWindowOpened = null
previous_info_window = null
...
close_window(){
if (this.previous_info_window != null ) {
  this.previous_info_window.close()
  }    
}

select_marker(data,infoWindow){
 if (this.previous_info_window == null)
  this.previous_info_window = infoWindow;
 else{
  this.infoWindowOpened = infoWindow
  this.previous_info_window.close()
 }
 this.previous_info_window = infoWindow
}
```

So every time a new window will be open it detect the event and closes the previous one, also this is working for closing a opened window if the user clicks outside the window in any other part of the map

Comment: Very good answer. Please mark it, so it can easily help others, they may pass over this answer if they don't see the green thick. Thank you a milion times!

Answer (score 5):

```html
<agm-map (mapClick)="mapClick($event)">
<agm-marker (markerClick)=markerClick(iw)>
<agm-info-window  #iw>
```

```
  currentIW: AgmInfoWindow;
  previousIW: AgmInfoWindow;

constructor(){
  this.currentIW = null;
  this.previousIW = null;
}

// other functions
mapClick() {
    if (this.previousIW) {
      this.previousIW.close();
    }
}

markerClick(infoWindow) {
    if (this.previousIW) {
      this.currentIW = infoWindow;
      this.previousIW.close();
    }
    this.previousIW = infoWindow;
}
```

Comment: You get an error Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. Bcoz mapClick($event) sends a parameter and in the function there is no parameter. There is no need of $event. Kindly edit your answer.

Comment: Accordingly to the latest API of @agm/core

https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap#mapClick

mapClick accepts an event

$event Type: EventEmitter<MouseEvent>

try to update your version

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use `isOpen` property in `agm-info-window`. This is a `boolean`. Let me know if you guys need a complete example

```
<agm-info-window [isOpen]="markerSelectIndex === index">
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution would be to pass `$event` parameter to `<agm-marker (markerClick)=markerClick($event)`.
This `$event` will be treated as `AgmMarker` and contains the `InfoWindow` in a QueryList if it has any.

```ts
class YourComponent {
  previousInfoWindow: AgmInfoWindow;

  markerClicked(agmMarker: AgmMarker): void {
    this.previousInfoWindow?.close();
    
    if (agmMarker.infoWindow.length) {
      this.previousInfoWindow = agmMarker.infoWindow.first as AgmInfoWindow;
    }
  }

  mapClicked(): void {
    this.previousInfoWindow?.close();
  }
}
```

```html
<agm-map (mapClick)="mapClicked()">
  <agm-marker (markerClick)="markerClicked($event)">
     <agm-info-window></agm-info-window>
   </agm-marker>
 </agm-map>
```