# Angular google map close info window on new marker click

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am using Angular google map: https://angular-maps.com/.
Right now as default functionality, it open the info-window defined inside marker.
And on click of any new marker it remains open old window. I need to close info window on click of another marker.
This is html code:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
          <agm-marker 
              *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
              (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.label, infoWindow, i)"
              [latitude]="m.lat"
              [longitude]="m.lng"
              [markerDraggable]="m.draggable"                
              [iconUrl]="m.icon">

            <agm-info-window #infoWindow>
              <strong>{{m.name}}</strong><br>
            </agm-info-window>

          </agm-marker>
        </agm-map>
```

this is code when marker is clicked:

```
clickedMarker(label: string, infoWindow, marker, index: number) {
     if( this.infoWindowOpened ===  infoWindow)
      return;

    if(this.infoWindowOpened !== null)
    {
     this.infoWindowOpened.close();
    }
    this.infoWindowOpened = infoWindow;
}
```

It works when the page refresh. But as soon as I refresh markers variable it show this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at InfoWindowManager.close (info-window-manager.js:48)
at AgmInfoWindow.close (info-window.js:94)
at SearchComponent.clickedMarker (search.component.ts:188)
```

component code to refresh markers:

```
this.markers.push({
              name: item.Name,  
              lat: parseFloat(item.latitude.toString()),
              lng: parseFloat(item.longitude.toString()),
              draggable: false,      
              icon:'assets/img/marker.png'
            });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can rewrite your `clickedMarker` very simple as follows

```js
previous;
...
clickedMarker(infowindow) {
    if (this.previous) {
      this.previous.close();
    }
    this.previous = infowindow;
  }
```

Make the change to your event binding function in the template

```html
(markerClick)="clickedMarker(infoWindow)"
```

The live code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/agm-close-infowindow)

Comment: But the error comes, when new marker is pushed in markers array in run time. Above code works fine, on initial page load.

Comment: Using the code of the answer, you can add markers dynamically. See the [live version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-jdajmh)

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem infoWindow is not closing automatically. in my scenario i have two buttons to show favourite and unfavourite icons on map. i'm calling **this.infoWindowOpened = null** in **ngOnInint()** on every favourite and unfavourite button click.so it is initialising every click as null. so it is solved my problem.. it may be helpful for others..

```
    ngOnInit() {
      this._mapService.selectedIcon.subscribe((res) => {
        this.infoWindowOpened = null;            
      });
    }
    if (this.infoWindowOpened === infoWindow)
       return;

    if (this.infoWindowOpened !== null && this.infoWindowOpened !== undefined)
        this.infoWindowOpened.close();

    this.infoWindowOpened = infoWindow;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for undefined in your code: "this.infoWindowOpened !== undefined"

```
public clickedMarker(label: string, infoWindow: any, marker: any, index: number) {

    if (this.infoWindowOpened === infoWindow) {
        console.log("window already opened");
        return;
    }

    if (this.infoWindowOpened !== null && this.infoWindowOpened !== undefined) {
        this.infoWindowOpened.close();
    }
    this.infoWindowOpened = infoWindow;
}
```

Comment: But, the close event will not work. My actual issue is, the infowindow should be closed as soon as I click on another marker.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, The problem is that all info windows are rendered again, when you renew the data. So the original don't exist anymore, making impossible to close.
To avoid this, use the trackBy function.